# Como trazer informação de arquivos em uma pasta

Tags: vba, imagem

Olá
Tenho que fazer uma análise qualitativa de imagens que estão no meu site, tenho todos os arquivos em uma pasta e preciso trazer duas informações para o Excel:
Nome do arquivo e suas dimensões.
[image: dimensões da imagem]

Comment: Salve, meu caro! Em que parte do seu código você tem alguma dúvida?

Comment: Salve, César!
Há algum tempo montei uma macro que lista todos os arquivos dentro da pasta e me permite renomeá-los, no entanto preciso que que a parte que lista os documentos traga também essa info de dimensão do arquivo, porém não sei fazer isso, segue abaixo o cód que lista os documentos: https://gist.github.com/gutosantos1/27fb78be22a6dfde7a3c7d7c0c39ab16

Answer (score 0):

As duas dimensões vêm juntas (provavelmente há uma propriedade que as traga separadas), mas testei aqui com uma imagem .jpg e consegui. É necessário fazer referência à biblioteca `Microsoft Shell Controls and Automations`.

```
Function PegarDimensoes() as String

Dim sh As New Shell32.Shell
Dim arq As Shell32.FolderItem
Dim CaminhoPasta As String
Dim NomeArquivo As String

CaminhoPasta = "C:\Users\usuarioTal\Desktop\"
NomeArquivo = "gatos_sorriso.jpg"

Set arq = sh.Namespace(CaminhoPasta).Items.Item(NomeArquivo)
PegarDimensoes = arq.ExtendedProperty("dimensions")

End Sub
```